# Unable to access bq status from command line during Dataflow + BigQuery job

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm submitting a Dataflow job that reads from and writes to a BigQuery dataset and table. The Dataflow job seems to work correctly.

During execution of the Dataflow job, the Dataflow UI tells me that I can check the status of the BigQuery export job by running a command using the `bq` tool.

[image: BigQuery command]

When I run that command I get a message that I'm not authorized to see the status. This is with the same authenticated account from which the Dataflow job was submitted.

```
BigQuery error in show operation: Access Denied: Job
bigquery-public-data:dataflow_job_2795433454065247350: The user
first.last@email.com does not have permission to access the job
bigquery-public-data:dataflow_job_2795433454065247350.
```

What incorrect security setting may be in place that causes this to happen?

---

The command I am running is

```
bq show -j --project_id=bigquery-public-data dataflow_job_2795433454065247350
```

Comment: Can you provide your dataflow job ID and I can take a look?

What command did you run? You can use <redacted> for the project name. I am surprised that it would be under the bigquery-public-data project as I believe this is a world-readable bigquery project. Does this match the project name you typed?

Comment: @LaraSchmidt I've added this to the question. I am reading from the bigquery-public-data project (just toy data), and this is what the Dataflow UI instructed me to use.

Comment: It may be a bug in Dataflow that it displays the project from which you are exporting rather than your own project. Are you able to execute `bq show -j --project_id=<your project name> dataflow_job_2795433454065247350`?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard yes - it was as simple as that. Thanks :)

Comment: Was about to suggest that. :) I'll make a note to get this fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the wrong project id in this case. You can find it by using the project that the dataflow job was run under as this is where the job will be.